# How to resolve NoClassFound dif error?

Tags: android

```
public class RegisterActivity  extends Activity{
   TextView tv1,tv2;
   Button b;
    EditText email,nname,npassword,phone,repassword,usernam;
   ImageView iv;
     Button btnCreateAccount;
    private DatabaseRegister dbHelper;
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.register);
//  dbHelper = new DatabaseRegister(this);
    dbHelper.open();

  initControls();
    }
       private void initControls()
      {
tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_register_job);
tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_fill_data);
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
       email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_email);
      nname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_name);
      npassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_password);
     phone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_phone);
       repassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_repass);
       usernam=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_username);
      iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_search);
   btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("click", "button");
   }
        });

          }
          private void ClearForm()
         {

        usernam.setText("");
           nname.setText("");
          npassword.setText("");
         email.setText("");
       repassword.setText("");
             phone.setText("");
          }
        private void RegisterMe(View v)
         {
//Get user details. 
String username = usernam.getText().toString();
String password = npassword.getText().toString();
String confirmpassword = repassword.getText().toString();
String name=nname.getText().toString();
String contact=phone.getText().toString();
String emailid=email.getText().toString();
//Check if all fields have been completed.
if (username.equals("") || password.equals("")||confirmpassword.equals("")||name.equals("")||contact.equals("")||email id.equals("")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "Please ensure all fields have been completed.",
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
    }

//Check password match. 
   if (!password.equals(confirmpassword)) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "The password does not match.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                npassword.setText("");
                repassword.setText("");
    return;
   }

//Encrypt password with MD5.
password = md5(password);

//Check database for existing users.
Cursor user = dbHelper.fetchUser(username, password, confirmpassword, emailid, name, contact);
if (user == null) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database query error",
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    startManagingCursor(user);

    //Check for duplicate usernames
    if (user.getCount() > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The username is already registered",
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        stopManagingCursor(user);
        user.close();
        return;
    }
    stopManagingCursor(user);
    user.close();
    user = dbHelper.fetchUser(username, password, emailid, name, contact, confirmpassword);
    if (user == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database query error",
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else {
        startManagingCursor(user);

        if (user.getCount() > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The username is already registered",
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            stopManagingCursor(user);
            user.close();
            return;
        }
        stopManagingCursor(user);
        user.close();
    }
    //Create the new username.
    long id = dbHelper.createUser(username, password, emailid, name, contact, confirmpassword);
    if (id > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your username was created",
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        saveLoggedInUId(id, username, password,confirmpassword, emailid, name,contact);
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

        finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failt to create new username",
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          }
     }

private void saveLoggedInUId(long id, String username, String password,String name,String contact,String email,String repass) {
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(login.MY_PREFS, 0);
Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putLong("uid", id);
editor.putString("username", username);
editor.putString("password", password);
editor.putString("repass", repass);
editor.putString("name", name);
editor.putString("emailid", email);
editor.putString("contact", contact);

editor.commit();
          }
         /**
         * Hashes the password with MD5.  
           *        @param s
        * @return
     */
      private String md5(String s) {
          try {

MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
digest.update(s.getBytes());
byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();


StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
for (int i=0; i<messageDigest.length; i++)
    hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));
return hexString.toString();

      } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
return s;
   }
     }
      }
```

I am making an login and register form in which my data will be store in SQLite database. When I click on register button it's giving me this error:

> NoClassFound diff

How can I resolve this?

Here is my logcat:

```
 11-06 06:03:32.951: I/dalvikvm(803): Could not find method      com.example.jobportal.RegisterActivity.RegisterMe
11-06 06:03:32.991: W/dalvikvm(803): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4635:   Lcom/android/database/DatabaseRegister;.fetchUser (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/database/Cursor;
11-06 06:03:32.991: D/dalvikvm(803): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x00b8
11-06 06:03:33.036: I/dalvikvm(803): Could not find method com.android.database.DatabaseRegister.open, referenced from method com.example.jobportal.RegisterActivity.onCreate
11-06 06:03:33.036: W/dalvikvm(803): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4636: Lcom/android/database/DatabaseRegister;.open ()Lcom/android/database/DatabaseRegister;
11-06 06:03:33.041: D/dalvikvm(803): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
11-06 06:03:33.570: D/AndroidRuntime(803): Shutting down VM
11-06 06:03:33.570: W/dalvikvm(803): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.database.DatabaseRegister
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at com.example.jobportal.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:38)
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-06 06:03:33.630: E/AndroidRuntime(803):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: and please follow java naming conventions...

Comment: sir i have posted my logcat....

Comment: it seems, you don't know how to accept an answer . please [see this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and accept if any answer worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not initialize dbHelper  object. Just replace the code as below.:

```
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.register);
     dbHelper = new DatabaseRegister(this);// you need to initialize it before access.
     dbHelper.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

For `NoClassDefFoundError` I had the same issue, I did the following to fix the problem.

1. Go to "Properties" of the project.
2. Select "Java Build Path"
3. Select "Order and Export" Tab
4. You should see the selected project's "src" and "gen" paths and dependencies here.
5. The order how they listed were first "src" and then "gen" path
6. I switch them, so that "gen" folder is build before the "src"

`gen` - automated code in project (from dependencies and references) 
`src` - source code in project

There was no need to restart the Eclipse. It just started working.

Answer (score -1):

you should Initialize btnCreateAccount

Comment: this should be a comment. Not an answer